# tSQLt AssertResultSetsHaveSameMetaData truncated response message in SQLTest

Tags: error-logging, tsqlt

I'm trying to use tSQLt `AssertResultSetsHaveSameMetaData` to check the metadata from a query that returns a large number of columns.

When it fails the message that details the 'expected/but was' details is truncated, so I can't the two pieces of information to see what is wrong.
Is there a way to output the message so that it doesn't truncate (for example, to a file)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are actually testing.  I agree that on wide result sets the output from AssertResultsSetsHaveSameMetaData can be a little unwieldy.  For stored procedures you would write your tests like this:

```
create procedure [ProcedureTests].[test SelectProcedure result set contract]
as
begin
    create table #expected
    (
      name varchar(500) not null
    , column_ordinal int not null identity(1,1)
    , system_type_name varchar(500) not null
    , Nullability varchar(16) not null
    )

   ; with expectedCte (name, system_type_name, Nullability)
    as
    (
                  select 'ItemId'                           , 'int'             , 'not null'
        union all select 'ActorId'                          , 'int'             , 'not null'
        union all select 'LanId'                            , 'nvarchar(200)'   , 'not null'
        union all select 'ConsumerId'                       , 'int'             , 'not null'
        union all select 'ConsumerMoniker'                  , 'nvarchar(200)'   , 'not null'
        union all select 'ProfileTypeId'                    , 'int'             , 'not null'
        union all select 'ProfileTypeName'                  , 'varchar(50)'     , 'not null'
        union all select 'ProfileId'                        , 'int'             , 'not null'
    )
    insert #expected
    (
      name
    , system_type_name
    , Nullability
    )
    select name, system_type_name, Nullability from expectedCte;

    --! Act
    select
          name
        , column_ordinal
        , system_type_name
        , case is_nullable when 1 then 'null' else 'not null' end as [Nullability]
    into
        #actual
    from
        sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(object_id('mySchema.SelectProcedure'), 0);

    --! Assert
    exec tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable #expected, #actual;
end;
go
```

Whilst for views you could use this (slightly different) approach:

```
alter procedure [ViewTests].[test ViewName resultset contract]
as
begin
    create table [ViewTests].[expected]
    (
      TransactionId int not null
    , SourceId int not null
    , SourceKey nvarchar(50) not null
    , TransactionTypeId int not null
    , TransactionStatusId int not null
    , LastModified datetime not null
    );
    --! You comparison may be as simple as this (but see alternative approach below)
    exec tSQLt.AssertEqualsTableSchema '[ViewTests].[expected]', 'mySchema.ViewName';


    --!
    --! Seems that is_nullable column on dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (used by tSQLt.AssertEqualsTableSchema)
    --! can be a bit flakey where views are concerned so you may need to ignore nullability when testing
    --! this view (so comment out that column in both SELECTs)
    --!
    select 
          c.name as [ColumnName]
        , c.column_id as [ColumnPosition]
        , case
            when st.name in ('char', 'varchar', 'varbinary')
                then st.name + '(' + case when c.max_length = -1 then 'max' else coalesce(cast(c.max_length as varchar(8)), '???') end + ')'
            when st.name in ('nchar', 'nvarchar')
                then st.name + '(' + case when c.max_length = -1 then 'max' else coalesce(cast(c.max_length / 2 as varchar(8)), '???') end + ')'
            when st.name in ('decimal', 'numeric')
                then st.name + '(' + coalesce(cast(c.precision as varchar(8)), '???') + ',' + coalesce(cast(c.scale as varchar(8)), '???') + ')'
            when st.name in ('time', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset')
                then st.name + '(' + coalesce(cast(c.precision as varchar(8)), '???') + ')'
            else st.name
            end as [DataType]
        , c.[precision] as [NumericScale]
        , c.scale as [NumericPrecision]
        , c.collation_name as [CollationName]
        , cast(case c.is_nullable when 1 then 'null' else 'not null' end as varchar(16)) as [Nullability]
    into
        #expected
    from
        sys.columns as c
    inner join sys.types as st
        on st.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
        and st.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    where
        c.[object_id] = object_id('[ViewTests].[expected]')

    select 
          name as [ColumnName]
        , column_ordinal as [ColumnPosition]
        , system_type_name as [DataType]
        , [precision ]as [NumericScale]
        , scale as [NumericPrecision]
        , collation_name as [CollationName]
        , cast(case is_nullable when 1 then 'null' else 'not null' end as varchar(16)) as [Nullability]
    into
        #actual
    from
        sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('select * from mySchema.ViewName, null, null)

    exec tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable '#expected',  '#actual' ;
end
go
```

In the even of any failures, the reason will be much clearer as the output is more like AssertEqualsTable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `EXEC [tSQLt].[XmlResultFormatter];` before running your test. This is intended for use in "build server" scenarios, but could probably be pressed into service to show you more of the output in SSMS.